# Monitoring PowerDNS

Tags: powerdns

I'm using PowerDNS with MySQL backend. I try to monitor how many request my server is handling. The built-in webserver is ok. But the statistics are not saved. If I restart the service, all data are losed.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to gather PowerDNS statistics via [Munin](https://github.com/avar/munin-pdns) and [Collectd](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:PowerDNS) Plugins for example you can have them exported automatically to [Graphite](https://graphiteapp.org/) or just use [PowerDNS "Graphing as a Service"](https://blog.powerdns.com/2014/12/11/powerdns-graphing-as-a-service/).